# Excel read-only for all users except the first one who got in the file

Tags: microsoft-excel, read-only

A couple months ago I had an excel file on a shared drive where the first one who got into this file was in the editable file, all the others who got in the file after the first one were in the read-only file. These people couldn't change to the editable file because someone was already in there.

Now, when we change an excel file to read-only, the people who are in the read-only file can actually change to the editable file. This is not what we want.

Has there been an update or something that changed this function? Or is there an other way to do this?

Comment: Have you set it to shared?

Comment: If you are using Excel's shared workbook feature, please make sure you can enable the feature for the workbook according to [About the shared workbook feature](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/about-the-shared-workbook-feature-49b833c0-873b-48d8-8bf2-c1c59a628534).